# Accessing replaced content in a php while loop

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop

I have a piece of code in my Wordpress website, that works perfectly bar one small thing.

This code below outputs a list of the posts within a specific category, and i have a bunch of logic about which template they should use, all works fine. I have this functionality whereby if a post is 'pinned', that post should be in this specific position within the layout - again works great. The only problem is that if there is a pinned post (which will always go into the array count of 1 (starting at 0)), the post that should've been there now never appears. What i'm doing is replacing what should of been in position 1 with my pinned logic, when really what i want to do is inserting that pinned logic before position 1

```
while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post();
                    if( $count === 1 ) {
                        //display pinned_featurette content
                        if ( $wpb_pinned_content_query->have_posts() ) {
                            while ( $wpb_pinned_content_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_pinned_content_query->the_post();
                                echo '<div class="grid-container-item pinned_ad '. get_the_ID() .'">';
                                        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-min-ad', get_post_format() );
                                echo '</div>';
                            endwhile;
                            wp_reset_postdata();
                        }
                        else {
                            echo '<div class="grid-container-item '.$count . '-' . get_the_ID() .'">';
                                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-min', get_post_format() );
                            echo '</div>';
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        if($pinnedID === get_the_ID()){
                        //dont show article again
                        // echo "im the pinned article duplicate";
                        }
                        else{
                            if( $count === 0 || $count === 9 ) {
                                echo '  <div class="grid-container-item '.$count . '-' . get_the_ID() .'">';
                                    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
                                echo '  </div>';
                            } 
                            else {
                                echo '<div class="grid-container-item '.$count . '-' . get_the_ID() .'">';
                                    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-min', get_post_format() );
                                echo '</div>';
                            }
                        }   
                    }
                    
    
                    $count ++;
                endwhile;
```

Any ideas on how i can get my original post in position 1 to output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when $count==1 you either display pinned or first...

what if

```
if( $count === 1 ) {
    //display pinned_featurette content
    if ( $wpb_pinned_content_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $wpb_pinned_content_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_pinned_content_query->the_post();
            echo '<div class="grid-container-item pinned_ad '. get_the_ID() .'">';
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-min-ad', get_post_format() );
            echo '</div>';
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
    // now display actual post #1
    if($pinnedID !== get_the_ID()) {
        echo '<div class="grid-container-item '.$count . '-' . get_the_ID() .'">';
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-min', get_post_format() );
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate - so simple when you see it like that

Comment: This code however brought to light another bug - be great to get your thoughts too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63918318/wp-reset-postdate-not-reseting-as-expected